# Error al instalar Cordova con npm en Windows 10

Tags: ionic, cordova, npm, windows10

Al ejecutar en consola (cmd) `npm install -g cordova` me aparece el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^4.3.x","shelljs":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-06T01_00_41_336Z-debug.log
```

el log es el siguiente:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'cordova',
1 verbose cli   'ionic' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose npm-session d89657513e490914
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic 1648ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for ionic@latest fetched in 1694ms
9 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova 2648ms (from cache)
10 silly pacote tag manifest for cordova@latest fetched in 2773ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
15 silly resolveWithNewModule ionic@3.20.0 checking installable status
16 silly resolveWithNewModule cordova@8.0.0 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/editor 374ms (from cache)
18 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-lib 390ms (from cache)
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for cordova-lib@8.0.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^4.3.x","shelljs":"'
20 silly pacote version manifest for editor@1.0.0 fetched in 406ms
21 silly resolveWithNewModule editor@1.0.0 checking installable status
22 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/update-notifier 687ms (from cache)
23 silly pacote version manifest for update-notifier@0.5.0 fetched in 718ms
24 silly resolveWithNewModule update-notifier@0.5.0 checking installable status
25 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore 781ms (from cache)
26 silly pacote version manifest for configstore@2.1.0 fetched in 829ms
27 silly resolveWithNewModule configstore@2.1.0 checking installable status
28 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-common 843ms (from cache)
29 silly pacote range manifest for cordova-common@^2.2.0 fetched in 1015ms
30 silly resolveWithNewModule cordova-common@2.2.3 checking installable status
31 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/insight 1734ms (from cache)
32 silly pacote version manifest for insight@0.8.4 fetched in 1750ms
33 silly resolveWithNewModule insight@0.8.4 checking installable status
34 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt 1781ms (from cache)
35 silly pacote version manifest for nopt@3.0.1 fetched in 1797ms
36 silly resolveWithNewModule nopt@3.0.1 checking installable status
37 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^4.3.x","shelljs":"'
37 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
37 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
37 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
37 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
37 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
38 verbose cwd C:\Users\gadgu
39 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
40 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
41 verbose node v8.11.2
42 verbose npm  v5.6.0
43 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^4.3.x","shelljs":"'
44 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado el cmd con permisos de administrador?

Comment: Lo que hice es buscar el "Símbolo del Sistema" y ejecutarlo como Administrador, pero si hay otra forma correcta me lo puedes decir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución parte le agradezco a TppShaka77.
Lo que hice fue desinstalar e instalar Node JS, y así funcionó.
Instalé, luego ejecute en el CMD como administrador `npm install`, y luego funcionó `npm install -g cordova` y `npm install -g ionic`

Answer (score 1):

Me ha pasado que al instalar npm en ocasiones el archivo "package-lock.json" no se configuro correctamente.

El archivo se encuentra en:

```
C:\Archivos de Programa\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Elimínalo y vuelve a correr el comando desde el cmd (con permisos de administrador) npm install.

De ese modo se regenerará el archivo "package-lock.json" de forma correcta y podrás instalar los package que necesites, como el Cordova.

Comment: Hola, en esa ubicación no tengo "package-lock.json", pero tengo "package.json", y el inicio del archivo es el siguiente:
{
  "version": "5.6.0",
  "name": "npm",
  "description": "a package manager for JavaScript",
  "keywords": [
    "install",
    "modules",
    "package manager",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "config": {
    "publishtest": false
  },
  "homepage": "https://docs.npmjs.com/",
  "author": "Isaac Z. Schlueter <i@izs.me> (http://blog.izs.me)",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/npm/npm"
  }

Comment: Te recomiendo entonces borrar toda la carpeta de `node_modules` y vuelve a correr el comando de  `npm install` De ahi vuelve a instalar Cordova. Todo esto desde la línea de cmd con permisos de adminsitrador.

Comment: Lo hice y me tiro el error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Comment: Eso te lo marca cuando intentas volver a correr el comando `npm install npm@latest` ?

Comment: ejecute ´npm install´, sin npm@latest